# Yii Framework - URL Manager and Rules for routing

Tags: php, yii, yii-routing

I have these default route rules in my urlManager in Yii framework:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

I have a `SiteController.php` for all the `/site/` requests. What I need now
is to redirect `/home` request to `/site/index`.

I've tried adding this array item:

```
'home' => '/site/index',
'/home' => 'site/index',
```

And none of them worked.

Can anyone solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the extra '/' slashes. This worked for me when I tested it just now:

```
'home' => 'site/index',
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
             'useStrictParsing'=>true,
        'rules'=>array(
                          '' => 'site/index',
                            'Home'=>'site/index',
```

first one will show empty instead of home.
second one will show Home instead of site/index